# Get Location of an empty with shrinkwarp constraint

Tags: python, constraints

I like to read the location values of an empty by a phyton script.
The empty has a shrinkwarp constraint an is projected to an plane (ground).

With >>>

```
bpy.data.objects['empty_left.005'].location
```

i get:

```
Vector((3.6352062225341797, 5.1430134773254395, 0.0))
```

but the z-value is the origin value and not the projection value.

If i use the z-value as a variable for a driver, the correct value is used:
[image: driver]

Comment: Could you upload your setup to pasteall.org/blend?

Comment: @user2488 just apply the visual transform before reading the values and you will get what you want

Comment: the empty follow a plane and change its z-value dynamicly, so i cannot apply the transformation! But the answer from pink vertex works fine!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the location from the [world matrix](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_8/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=object.matrix_world#bpy.types.Object.matrix_world):

```
empty.matrix_world.translation
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to apply the visual transform 'which apply the constraint transform' to get the actual location of your object :

```
import bpy
ob = bpy.data.objects['Empty']
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = ob
bpy.ops.object.visual_transform_apply()
print(ob.location)
```